# ReactiveUI - "reset" Changed of ReactiveObject

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a property "CurrentCompany" on my ViewModel, the property itself is inherited from ReactiveObject and declared as OAPH:

```
private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<CompanyDTO> _currentCompany;
public CompanyDTO CurrentCompany => _currentCompany.Value;
```

Then I have a ReactiveCommand which calls an asynchronous task to save changes of my object:

```
SaveCompanyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveCompanyDTO, canSaveCommand);
```

The "canSaveCommand" is defined as follows:

```
var canSaveCommand = (this)
    .WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.CurrentCompany.Changed)
    .Select(_ => true);
```

This all works as expected, the button to which my SaveCompanyCommand is bind to is disabled, I change something on my CurrentCompany-object and the button gets enabled.
What I do not know: after executing the SaveCompanyDTO-Task I want the button to be disabled again. How can I tell reactiveui that my CurrentCompany-object is unchanged and fresh again? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your implementation of canSaveCommand is always selecting true. Instead, you should select the value of Changed.

Comment: "Changed" is not a boolean but of type "IObservable<IReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<IReactiveObject>>" The EventArgs tell me the name of the property that has changed. That means when I change a letter on a property called "Name" the Changed-Event fires and tells me "Property 'Name' has changed". But when I save my record how can I tell my ReactiveObject that it should start again watching for changes?

Comment: Oh, instead of using Changed (which I don’t see often), I  would have a reactive IsDirty property in the company class that you base canSaveCommand on.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answers.

I finally found a solution; don't know if it is elegant but it works!
First, I introduced another boolean property on my ViewModel named "HasChanges". The "canSaveCommand" reacts on every change of this property:

```
IObservable<bool> canSaveCommand = (this)
    .WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.HasChanges);
```

Then I watch for changes on my object:

```
_ = (this)
    .WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.CurrentCompany.Changed)
    .Subscribe(c =>
    {
        HasChanges = true;
    });
```

And after executing my ReactiveCommand I reset HasChanges again to false:

```
SaveCompanyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveCompanyDTO, canSaveCommand);
 _ = SaveCompanyCommand.Subscribe(c =>
        {
            HasChanges = false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I do not know: after executing the SaveCompanyDTO-Task I want the button to be disabled again.

If you only want to disable the button after executing the command, you can try using a subject:

```
Subject<bool> canExecuteSubject = new Subject<bool>();
SaveCompanyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveCompanyDTO, canExecuteSubject);

Observable.Merge(
    // enable button after every change
    this.WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.CurrentCompany.Changed).Select(_ => true),
    // disable button after execution
    SaveCompanyCommand.Select(_ => false))
.Subscribe(canExecuteSubject);
```

> How can I tell reactiveui that my CurrentCompany-object is unchanged
>   and fresh again?

If you always want to know if the Company-object is unchanged after saving, I would add a property to the CompanyDTO class itself and use it for `canExceute` in the SaveCompanyCommand.